# Objective-C SpriteKit: Stopping left tower only

Tags: objective-c, scroll, sprite-kit, touchesbegan, skaction

So, I have a game where towers spawn on the right of the screen and move to the left, like they're scrolling. The towers are constantly going up-and-down, but I'd like to have it so when I touch the screen, the leftmost tower ***moving up-and-down*** will stop moving up-and-down (of course, still scrolling).

I haven't really had too much time to think about it, but I came up with a few good ideas. For one, I'm thinking that I'll just create a "touched"
function, and call it when the `touchesBegan()` is called. I must do that for complicated reasons I won't explain. So far I came up with this code:

```
- (void)touched
{
    SKSpriteNode *lastSprite;
    for (SKSpriteNode *sprite in self.scene.children) {
        if (lastSprite && sprite) {
            if (sprite.position.x < lastSprite.position.x) {
                [sprite removeAllActions];
            }
        }

        lastSprite = sprite;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I commented out that code bit by bit and a problem occurs when using the fast-enumeration "for-in" statement. The towers will all scroll to the left, but they won't go up-and-down at all; even though this function never gets called anywhere!

So that's one thing I've tried. I've also tried using `enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:`, but that doesn't work because it needs to be an `SKNode`, while my towers are `SKSpriteNodes`. Plus, it's difficult for me to grab a hold of all the children in the scene that way. But I think using the towers' names will be helpful, right?

Please help me out! Some code snippets would be helpful, too!

---

**EDIT:**

I tried changing the `touched()` method to this:

```
- (void)touched
{
    NSArray *sceneNodes = self.scene.children;
    SKSpriteNode *lastNode = nil;
    for (SKSpriteNode *sprite in sceneNodes) {
        if (lastNode && sprite) {
            if (sprite.position.x < lastNode.position.x) {
                [sprite removeAllActions];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function worked in itself, and the towers continued to go up-and-down, but when I put it in the `touchesBegan()`, even when I don't touch, it stops going up-and-down just as before.

Comment: Little confused on what you want. You say "the leftmost tower not moving will stop moving...". If the left most tower 'not moving' has to 'stop moving'... that does not make sense. What exactly are you trying to do? Also, how are you pinpointing which tower you are targeting for action?

Comment: @sangony That's my bad. I'll edit that bold/italic part to say "moving up-and-down". What I'm aiming for is that ALL the towers are initially scrolling from right to left, and going up-and-down. When I tap the screen, it finds all the towers still moving up-and-down, and then finds the leftmost one. It grabs that tower and stops it from moving up-and-down (when I tap the screen). But the other towers to the right are still scrolling to the left AND moving up-and-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the basic steps I suggest you follow:

If you are subclassing (SKSpriteNode) your towers then create a BOOL property, something like BOOL movingUpDown, and set it to YES for any tower that has vertical movement.

If you are not subclassing your towers, use the userData dictionary to create an entry which tells you if vertical movement is present.

Next, add all tower objects into a mutable array. I personally prefer adding unique name to each object at the time of creation. Something like "node-0", "node-1" and so on. You can do this by having a counter and adding the value to each object's name.

In the touchesBegan method you have your stop vertical movement code. If you are adding the tower objects sequentially, the first tower object should be the most left object.

```
SKSpriteNode *myNode = [self.myArray firstObject];
// set vertical movement to zero

// remove the first object in the array
[self.myArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Your code is probably a bit different but you can use the above to get the gist of what you can do to make it work.

Comment: My game is using the technique for parallax scrolling, where it doesn't remove the towers when they get to the left of the screen, it just places them at the right and reuses them. Will this code mess that up?

Comment: @ChristianKRider - That's fine. In that case you do not remove the tower object from the array but you have to use code identifying the left most tower in the array. What happens after that depends on your code.

Comment: This was a great idea, @sangony! It was a little bit off, but that's because you didn't know everything about my project. I tweaked it up a little bit, but it worked perfectly afterword! I'll mark this as accepted (especially since no one else answered, anyway).